# add double httpHeaders

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I want to add httpHeader to my response

I thought to use this code:

```
private void AddCustomHeader()
         {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Response.Headers.Get("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")))
             {
                 // Custom header
                 HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
             }
         }
```

But it will always fails on localhost when ran with VS_server

```
This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.
```

What will happen if I add a header that already exists?

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("name","value");
```

Comment: what is exactly HttpContext.Response ? AFAIK it should be HttpContext.Current.Response

Comment: instead of the whole block, have you tried :
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); ?

Comment: @jbl how would that help?

Comment: @AntonioBakula so what is the difference?

Comment: It answers your question "What will happen if I add a header that already exists?" : the already existing header will be replaced.
About the exception you get, in VS ,open your web project properties, Web => check "Use Local IIS Web Server" (instead of "Use VS Development Server"). Depending on your configuration, you might need to check "Use IIS Express"

Comment: @jbl the question is what will happen when the header doesn't exist. It will throw excpetion? I couldn't find on MSDN

Comment: what do you mean by "header doesn't exist" ? Custom header ? No exception will be thrown. You can set (almost) anything you want.
BTW, this should be of some help for custom headers http://stackoverflow.com/a/15043027/1236044

Comment: @jbl can you submit an answer? I want to approve yours. I have used the `Set` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say (to sum-up comments) that, you should try to use :

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

as

1. it will replace any existing value for the corresponding header
2. `Response.AddHeader` is just there to maintain compatibility with previous versions

About the exception you get, you should try to open your web project properties, "Web" => check "Use Local IIS Web Server" (instead of "Use VS Development Server").

Depending on your configuration, you might need to check "Use IIS Express"

Also, this should be of some help for custom headers https://stackoverflow.com/a/15043027/1236044

Comment: @Iainyou should post your own question with whole context

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the *This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode* error:

1. Select the Application Pool in IIS Manager
2. Click "Basic Settings..."
3. Make sure "Integrated" mode is selected for "Managed pipeline mode" in the dialog

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/post/2329580.aspx).

In regards to your second question (what will happen if you add a header that already exists) it will just add another value with the same name:

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("name", "value1");
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("name", "value2");
```

Will result in a header with a name `name` and a value `value1, value2` (tried in ASP.NET 4.5, IIS Express, though I doubt this matters much.)

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi I know how to confiugre the IIS, I was asking about the Visual-studio local server

Comment: @EladBenda According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1774462/88709), `Response.Headers` isn't supported with Cassini or IIS 6.

Comment: On IIS Express 8, in Application_BeginRequest if I add             `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("name", "value1");        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("name", "value2");` for some reason I get two headers `name: value1` and `name: value2` instead of one `name: value1, value2`